# Android eclipse java.lang.Throwable cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, osx-lion

I am trying to compile an Android project which was built by some on else on windows.

Here is my platform: 
Mac OS X 10.7 Lion, Eclipse for Java Developers installed today (Indigo Service Release 1)
Java on mac: javac -version
javac 1.6.0_29

Am seeing the following error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The type java.lang.Throwable cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced 
     from required .class files
    - The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
     required .class files
    - The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
     required .class files
    - The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
     required .class files
```

I am guessing it may be something to do with path or availability of libraries, however not sure how to proceed next. Appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the answer here: [stackoverflow.com/questions/6614380/jdk-on-osx-10-7-lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614380/jdk-on-osx-10-7-lion)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Android tools and at least one Android platform installed?

That is, have you followed the steps here:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html#InstallingADT

Once you have, ensure that you have installed the same platform version that the app is linked against. You can check this by looking at the project Properties -> Android section.

If all of that is good, please provide more information about your configuration.

Comment: Yeah, I followed the instructions. By default it downloaded the latest 4.0 sdk but I went into window->Androidsdk manager and downloaded 2.3, 2.2 and 2.1 sdk's. I created an avd for 2.3 target which was the project built against.

Comment: got the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614380/jdk-on-osx-10-7-lion