# Why is VPN connection on Mac OS X causing Eclipse to lockup during 'edit launch config' operation?

Tags: eclipse, macos, vpn

I have been using Eclipse on Mac OS X from home over a VPN to develop GWT and perl code in a local workspace for my employer.  Recently a repeatable and severe lockup began occurring whenever I tried to edit Debug (or Run) launch configurations.  I got the spinning beachball of death (SBOD) and, if I waited long enough (10-15 minutes) it would eventually stop and I could at least close the dialog.

I tried numerous things until a coworker suggested trying it with VPN turned off.  To my surprise (and somewhat delight) it began behaving normally in the above scenario.  I have been using Eclipse in this manner for about a year with no problems so naturally I am racking my brain trying to think of recent changes to VPN and/or to my split tunnel script (euphemistically called 'multihome') that could account for this abnormal behavior.  This lockup occurs with or without the split tunnel.

I should also point out that the "initializing Java tooling" progress status ALWAYS occurs when starting eclipse and takes about a minute to complete with VPN connection.  Normal (<2 seconds)  without.

So, I'm starting to learn how to use wireshark and possibly will look into using packetlogger as well in an attempt to find out more about this strange issue.

Anyone have a clue as to what might be causing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Cannot resolve host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720780/cannot-open-eclipse-marketplace-cannot-install-remote-marketplace-locations-can)

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard one to answer.  Short answer is "I don't know".
However, I did find out that, due to the recently updated JVM, done as part of the Mac OS X update, Eclipse IDE lost its ability to find the src.jar file for the JRE.  As a result, it appears that Eclipse, in various places in the code, searched for this file and when not found attempted to find it via the network.  When VPN was turned on, perhaps this exacerbated the problem.

This was solved by fixing the Installed JRE configuration of Eclipse (see [JDK on OSX 10.7 Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614380/jdk-on-osx-10-7-lion)).