# Use JavaFX without Java7u9 On OSX - Snow Leopard

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, javafx

I would like to use JavaFX in one of my project. I know it comes with `Java7-Update9`, but the machine that I'm using only supports up to `Java7-Update2`. (This is an `OSX-Snow Leopard`)

Does any one have a suggestion on how to do this?
THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JavaFX is part of Oracle Java for Java 7 update 6 and later for Windows, OS X and Linux](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

[JavaFX 2.2 is currently available as a separate download for Windows](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html) for some versions of Java not including JavaFX (Java 6 and Java 7 versions before update 6).

JavaFX is not available for OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard).

JavaFX is not available for Java versions prior to Java 7 update 6 for OS X or Linux.

(This answer refers to the current JavaFX 2+ version, not the obsolete JavaFX 1.x version - use of the obsolete version is not recommended).

Comment: So long story short, I'd just need a different machine to work on? :(

Comment: Not to raise a 'religious wall', but this is why I hate Apple! And thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot verify this (I don't know how to use JavaFX), I do know that it is possible to force install the latest Java 7 (update 14) on Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard):
[How to install java jdk 7 on Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536667/how-to-install-java-jdk-7-on-snow-leopard)