# Is there any way to install google app engine 1.7.2 manually?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I've read lots of posts related to my question, but I couldn't find a solution.

I'm developing an Android app using CSE (custom search engine) under Eclipse Indigo and JDK 6.

The problem is:

1. My current JDK version is 6 (last App Engine compatible version for JDK 6 is 1.7.2)
2. The current App Engine version is 1.8.8 (for JDK 7)
3. To upgrade my JDK 6 to 7, I must install Mavericks OS (I have Snow Leopard). I don't want to do this right now.

I've tried to install App Engine 1.7.2 by downloading the jar and adding as

`Eclipse->Preferences->Google->App Engine->Add...`

but I get the error "Failed to initialize App Engine SDK.

So, is there any other way to install it by hand and keep my current configuration??

Thanks in advance.

Isaac.

Answer (score 0):

You could, but there's no point, since the App Engine production environment is running 1.8.8.  So you might make it work locally, but it wouldn't work when you deploy.

There are various tutorials around which describe how to install Java 7 on Snow Leopard, though, such as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536667/how-to-install-java-jdk-7-on-snow-leopard).

Comment: Mmmm....I didn't know about the possibility to install JDK 7 in that way. I'll try it. Thanks a lot Daniel for your answer.

Comment: Finally, I installed Java 7. But when I used it in eclipse...I can't open it any more :( I had to install Kepler instead, and I got other errors related to Google plugin for eclipse. What a mess! :)