# How to install JDK 8 on Mac OS X Snow Leopard?

Tags: java, macos, installation, java-8, requirements

According to the system requirements, even Java 7 requires Lion, but then I found this question: [How to install java jdk 7 on Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13536667). Especially the answer stating that java 7 doesn't, in fact, require 10.7 and that this restriction can just be removed from the .pkg gives hope that it is possible to install even Java 8 on Snow Leopard. Any information on this?

Comment: Have you tried following the steps in Niksa Jakovljevic's blog post?  Seems like it's a lot simpler than messing around with the .pkg

Comment: @Foosh Nice catch, thank you! I missed it since it has relatively so few votes. I would prefer, though, to know wether the requirement is "real" before I run an installer that is not compatible with my OS.

Comment: Is there a specific reason as to why you would want to linger on an unsupported dist of the OS?

Comment: @Martin I don't want to, my iMac is just too old to upgrade.

Comment: Same boat. What did you end up doing?

Comment: @MatthewCornell Not upgrading and having another computer. Sorry!

Comment: FYI I tried it and got errors. Interestingly, the latest Python runs fine on 10.6 ;-)

Comment: @MatthewCornell Python is less OS dependent; no GUI and relatively little low level stuff. Java's AWT and multithreadihg facilities are - I believe - lower level than their Python equivalents. I don't know Python very well though.

Comment: @11684 good points. At the same time, how much do internals change in each OS X version?

Comment: @MatthewCornell Coincidentally I just read about that a few days ago. OS X internals change a lot between versions, apparently. I don't think I can remember where I read this though.

Comment: I did find it in my browser history: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235335/the-linux-kernel-breaking-user-space. Just a passing remark in [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/235338/37709) to that question. @MatthewCornell

Comment: thanks, @11684. I'd be curious to hear a Java expert's explanation of why the lack of OS X backwards compatibility...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OS level requirements are "real" and shouldn't normally be circumvented.  As to how real it is I cannot answer.  Ultimately as system libraries are updated, and newer versions of JDK are compiled against them older systems won't be able to use parts of Java that use the newer functions in those libraries or even the libraries as a whole if the pointers/links have changed.

If you want to be absolutely sure Java will work on your system, you will need to compile it from source.  But that is a massive pain on a Mac unfortunately.  If you want to try anyway, check out the [Mac Port Project](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/macosx-port/) over on OpenJDK.

Answer (score 0):

In a recent development Jazzzny made java 17 for Mountain Lion and up possible.
As well as Java 11 for Snow Leopard and up. This should be useful.

https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/java-17-for-10-8-10-9-10-10-and-10-11-java-11-for-10-6-10-11-jdk.2395323/

https://github.com/Jazzzny/jdk-macos-legacy/releases

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).