# Setting up Java Development Kit (JDK) on Mac 10.6.8

Tags: java, osx-snow-leopard

I need help setting up `Java Development Kit (JDK`) on **Mac 10.6.8**. I'm trying to take the following online self-paced course: http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/95-815/.

I've managed to install `"OpenJDK 7 version 1.7.0"` by using "Pacifist" and momentarily altering my

`"/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist"`

file as directed in this post: [How to install java jdk 7 on Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536667/how-to-install-java-jdk-7-on-snow-leopard). I've also moved `"OpenJDK 7 version 1.7.0"` to the top priority in `Java Preferences`. However, upon entering `java -version` in Terminal, I receive the output

`-bash: java: command not found`.

On the other hand, when I enter `/usr/bin/java -version`, I receive the following output:

```
openjdk version "1.7.0-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-internal-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)
```

I suspect that my issue has to do with establishing the correct **PATH**, however, I have no idea how to do this and all the guides I find are too cryptic for me to understand. Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: enter `javac` for java compiler, java is for the run time and yes you need to set the `JAVA_HOME`variable I suspect like you do on a Linux system.

Comment: @jgr208, When I enter: 
`Jons-MacBook:~ dreadnought74$ javac Users/dreadnought74/Desktop/JavaCMU/MyFirstJavaPgm.java`

Terminal returns the following:
`-bash: javac: command not found`

Comment: http://java.dzone.com/articles/installing-openjdk-7-os-x

Comment: @jgr208, I appreciate your help. I'm beyond frustrated at this point. Is it possible the code from the referenced thread is the issue?:
`echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home' >> ~/.profile`

In trying to follow your "dzone" guide, I'm assuming I can ignore the 'David Blevin's handy setjdk script' since my `Java Preferences` allows me to move JDK 1.7.0 to the top priority. However, running `sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk` results in another `command not found` error.

Comment: hmmm that is a softlink, but maybe its best at this time to uninstall and do a fresh install?

Comment: You mean simply deleting the `Java` folder and reinstalling? I've tried that as well. I'll continue troubleshooting and report back if I find anything else.

Comment: doing however mac does uninstalling of packages

Comment: OK, seem to have made some progress resetting my path with this

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22859/uh-oh-bash-ls-command-not-found

'"PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

You can reset the path by typing the above into a shell window, and then typing export PATH"'