# jnlp file is prompting mac to download JRE, but its already installed (Java 1.6.0_37) Mac OSX 10.7.5

Tags: java, macos, jnlp, java-web-start

I don't even really know what to post in here except for the fact that the terminal on the computer says:

```
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)
```

but for some reason when i run the JNLP file a prompt pops up saying that to open this web start application I need to download the Java Runtime Environment. Which I already did. It originally installed Java 7, and after doing some research I discovered that this jnlp file won't open with Java 7 installed. So I went back and removed Java 7, and now this is happening.

If I open the Java Preferences window, I can see that Java SE 6 is indeed installed. I just have no idea what to do.

### EDIT:

The terminal says

```
No Java runtime present, requesting install. Unable to locate a Java Runtime to invoke.
```

when I put in

```
javaws /(path).jnlp
```

Also I ran janela, and got this report:

JaNeLA Report - version 11.05.17

```
Report for file:/Users/administrator/Desktop/Final%20Cut%20Server.jnlp

Content type application/xml does not equal expected type of application/x-java-jnlp-file
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'icon'. One of '{title}' is expected.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'icon'. One of '{title}' is expected.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'j2se'. One of '{jar, nativelib, extension, property, package}' is expected.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'j2se'. One of '{jar, nativelib, extension, property, package}' is expected.
XML encoding not known, but declared as utf-8
Codebase + href 'http://10.13.144.50/~fcsvr/webstart/macJnlp.php' is not equal to actual location of 'file:/Users/administrator/Desktop/Final%20Cut%20Server.jnlp'.
Desktop icons were subject to bug nnnn in earlier J2SE versions
Optimize this application for off-line use by adding the <offline-allowed /> flag.
The HREF of '/~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer.jar' could be optimized to '~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer.jar'.
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for '/~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer.jar'.
The resource download at /~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at /~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the /~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for /~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
The HREF of '/~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer_MacOSX.jar' could be optimized to '~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer_MacOSX.jar'.
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for '/~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer_MacOSX.jar'.
The resource download at /~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer_MacOSX.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the /~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer_MacOSX.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for /~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer_MacOSX.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
The HREF of '/~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer_MacOSX.jar' could be optimized to '~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer_MacOSX.jar'.
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for '/~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer_MacOSX.jar'.
The resource download at /~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer_MacOSX.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the /~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer_MacOSX.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for /~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer_MacOSX.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Resource type icns of resource ~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer.icns is not one of the allowable types of gif, jpg, jpeg.
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for '~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer.icns'.
Icon loading & use can be optimized by specifying the width and height for ~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer.icns
Resource type icns of resource ~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer.icns is not one of the allowable types of gif, jpg, jpeg.
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for '~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer.icns'.
Icon loading & use can be optimized by specifying the width and height for ~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer.icns
Resource type png of resource ~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer.png is not one of the allowable types of gif, jpg, jpeg.
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for '~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer.png'.
Icon loading & use can be optimized by specifying the width and height for ~fcsvr/webstart/FinalCutServer.png
The HREF of '/FinalCutServer' could be optimized to 'FinalCutServer'.
Note that a java/j2se version of 'n.n*' will limit the app. to that  specific Java runtime, and no later.  It is often better to specify  version as 'n.n+'.
Note that a java/j2se version of 'n.n*' will limit the app. to that  specific Java runtime, and no later.  It is often better to specify  version as 'n.n+'.
```

I'm sorry i know its a lot, but I don't even know what is important and what isn't. Hope this helps.

Comment: 1) Check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/) (clear any errors, flush the cache and try it again.  If it still fails..)  2) Post it as an edit to the question. 3) Let me know when you have done that.

Comment: Version 1.6.0_39 is now extant via software update. See also this [article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5575).

Comment: I well run Janela, and post what I get later today. Do either if you know if it is possible to get one version newer than what I have seeing as how it is disabled? Keep in mind I don't want Java 7

Answer (score 1):

As discussed [here](http://developers.slashdot.org/story/13/02/03/1431227), Apple disabled this and earlier versions of Java pending a security update. Version 1.6.0_39 is now extant via software update, as described [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5575) and [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1222).

Comment: I can't seem to get the security update 12 to show up in software update... i found the file on softpedia, so i will try to install it from there

Comment: Wellllll according to the dmg i downloaded from Apple, this version isn't compatible with 10.7.5 and is only compatible with 10.6, which I am finding hard to believe. Any other advice?

Comment: Update your question to mention 10.5.7 explicitly; AFAIK, Apple doesn't support Java 6 on 10.7+, but there may be a workaround. Did anything turn up in checking your `.jnlp`?

Comment: Ok so as far as I can tell there is no Java 1.6.0_39 for OSX 10.7.5... I might have missed it somewhere but I can't seem to find it. Also, check the edit i made to the question.

Comment: You might look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6614380/230513) about Java 6 on 10.7. See also [*jnlp mime type*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/faq.html#s223).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this solution here worked just fine:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Oracle Java 7, you can run `jnlp` files with:

```
'/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/javaws' file.jnlp
```

If you would want, you can also replace `/usr/bin/javaws` file with a symlink to `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/javaws`.