# Downloading jnlp files prompts java download

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

When I'm trying to download the jnlp file for our application the jnlp file is not downloaded. Instead I'm prompted to download java even though java already is installed.

The only thing even remotely relevant I've found is [this question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654289/jnlp-file-is-prompting-mac-to-download-jre-but-its-already-installed-java-1-6) but that talks about Mac.

I'm using windows 7, IE 10 and the installed java version is 7.25. The minimum required version in the jnlp file is 1.6.

It works on other computers but not on this one.

Hopefully someone knows something because i don't even know where to start...

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify Java 1.6 *or later* in the JNLP.  This is typically done by requiring "`1.6+`".

You can also enable verbose logging in the Java Console to get hints about what JWS is doing, but unfortunately not all make sense without looking at the underlying source.

Answer (score 0):

If JRE 1.6 or later is installed and still you are faceing this problem then configure the browser by doing folowing steps:

1. Click Start.
2. Click Control Panel.
3. Click Programs
4. Click Default Programs.
5. Click Associate a file type or protocol with a program.
6. Click extension jnlp.
7. Click change Program.
8. Select javaws or navigate to C:\Program Files\java\jre7\bin\javaws.exe